# Vector intersection with a surface

Tags: python, vector

I have a collection of line of sight vectors, and I'm trying to figure out where those vectors intersect any random surface. I have several random surfaces with their own unique line of sight vectors. I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the 'line of sight vector' of a surface?

Comment: The line of sight vector is of a point away from the respective surface. The problem I'm facing is trying to figure out where this line intersects the surface.